# How to build single jar file containing multiple java modules using gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, modularity

I'm working on a project that has to be divided among multiple modules. I use this project as an example before I'll start messing around with a real one: https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin-example
The problem is I can't force gradle to build single working jar. Instead I'm getting multiple corrupted jars that contain classes only from its own module. I've tried modul plugin already but with no luck.